# BSD atos available on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debug-symbols, bsd

Is the atos binary for converting numberic addresses to symbols of binary images available on Linux, specifically Ubuntu? It seems to only be available on OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that automagically translates addresses; you will need to pick through the output of `nm` or `objdump` instead.

Comment: Sounds like something that's not worth doing for our case, since we can run it on OS X. Thanks!

Comment: @marcog You're wrong, I'd prefer to do symbolication on my webserver to receive human readable stack traces in bugtracker web-interface!

Comment: @Tertium I'm symbolicating on OS X and uploading the results to a web server.

Comment: @marcog In manual mode? I'm currently developing bugtracking system. App sends reports (actually only last stack trace on crash/signal) to webserver, so I have to download stacks list and then pass it to my symbolicating tool (works using atos). It symbolicates all stacks at once but I'd prefer to remove this manual step and see readable stacks. How have you solved this?

Comment: @Tertium Our app also sends crash reports to our webserver (we use http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/), then I have a script which reads them from the webserver, symbolicates, and writes back to the webserver. I'd love to push that process onto the webserver if there was an easy enough way, but it's not worth our time and effort if the above answer is the only way.

Comment: @marcog It seems that this is actually the best solution. I hoped to find  atos sources, but now I assume they are private, alas

Answer (score 3):

Atosl from facebook - https://github.com/facebook/atosl

To get it running on ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libdwarf-dev binutils-dev
git clone git@github.com:facebook/atosl.git
cd atosl
make
```

Comment: If you are trying to desymbolicate ios crashes on linux you either have to wait for https://github.com/facebook/atosl/pull/15 to be merged or use this fork https://github.com/ccarnero/atosl.

Comment: This does not seem to support arm64, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

A similar tool named [addr2line](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/addr2line.html) in binutils.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer**

`llvm-symbolizer-15` of the `llvm-15` package in Ubuntu gives equivalent results.

`llvm-symbolizer --demangle --relativenames --obj=$DSYM_DIR/Contents/Resources/DWARF --adjust-vma=$BASE_ADDRESS -p $ADDRESS`

If you have specific requirements for using atos, then see the old answer below.

**Old answer**

For analyzing iOS binaries with atos in Linux (and should work for MacOS binaries too), I used [Darling][1] with Xcode 11.3.1.

Note: an old Xcode version is required since newer versions depend on system libraries that are not up-to-date in Darling. Probably a version newer than 11.3.1 should work, but this is the first and last I tried.

Instructions:

1. Install Xcode, see [Installing Software in Darling][2]. Essentially, copy Xcode.app in /Applications, from inside the darling shell. You can download all versions of Xcode [here][3], and you should use [Unxip][4] to unpack the .xip file.
2. Run `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/atos`
3. You can actually remove Xcode to use only atos, by copying the Atos' shared libraries and creating an opportune directory structure to preserve the `rpath`:

   ```
      mkdir -p atos-bin/Developer/usr/bin/
      mkdir -p atos-bin/SharedFrameworks/
      cd atos-bin
      cp /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/atos Developer/usr/bin/
      cp -r /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/SymbolicationDT.framework SharedFrameworks
      cp -r /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/CoreSymbolicationDT.framework SharedFrameworks

      # run atos
      ./Developer/usr/bin/atos -arch arm64 -l 0x1072c4000 -o dsym/MyLib.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MyLib 0x00000001073ee0b4
   ```

```
  [1]: https://github.com/darlinghq/darling
  [2]: https://docs.darlinghq.org/installing-software.html
  [3]: https://developer.apple.com/download/all/
  [4]: https://github.com/saagarjha/unxip
```